# Showing that an element in the kernel generates the kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have found an element which is in the kernel, however I am not sure as to what are the **steps** to prove it generates the entire kernel.

I am considering a map from $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[t]$ defined by $\phi(x) = t$ and $\phi(y) = t^2$. I know that $x^2 -y$ is in the kernel and I know that the kernel is an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but I am not sure how to show that $\text{ker}(\phi) = (x^2 - y)$ - or even whether that's the case.

Comment: A single element of a kernel need not generate the kernel. Particularly the identity doesn't if the kernel is not trivial. And the kernel of what? A group homomorphism? A ring homomorphism? You probably need to add the specifics of the problem you are looking at.

Comment: Please elaborate on what the homomorphism is you are talking about - give context.

Comment: Kernel of _what_? Generates in what sense???

Comment: a map from C[x,y] --> C[t] defined by phi(x) = t and phi(y) = t^2

Comment: I know to find something in the kernel, you can find t in terms of x, then say y = t^2 =(x)^2, so you know that x^2-y is in the kernel, but how do I show this generates the kernel?

Comment: @epsilonolispe You should edit that into the question.

Comment: he means the unique $\mathbb{C}$-algebra morphism satisfying etc.. this is very much clear from context

Answer (score 1):

Hint: division with remainder with respect to $y$.